# "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" when trying to connect mySql via servlet

Tags: mysql, sql, servlets, jdbc, jar

I try to connect to MySQL database (works perfect when I connect to it  without servlet) and get the below error all the time:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

This error means (as I understand) that I don't have some jar files in my project. but this is not true, because I have those Jars. !Moreover, if I realy didn't had those jar, I could not have connected to the database anyway.

What I missed?

Comment: If you're running tomcat you can probably drop it into the lib directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at those tags this is a web application. So the error clearly states you don't have your SQL Venders Driver jars in the class path.

You can put this jar in your Project/WEB-INF/lib folder and restart whatever web server you are using. Then you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql jdbc jar driver isn't in your classpath.

If you run it from a servlet, it uses the classpath of your servlet container. This classpath probably contains it.

Find mysql-connector-java where you can, and copy into your classpath.

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge, but i'm not sure how to do it. i saw here a guide that say only to copy it to the src folder. is it correct? anyway-his way doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @dennisbergkamp You are on a large q&a site, formulate your question and ask it. It is absolutely not a problem here, if you ask a lot.

Comment: can u explain please how to add the jar to classpath? i don't find an answer for that, and also posted it and didn't answered yet. thanks

Comment: @dennisbergkamp Yes, but it is already a different question. Ask this as a new one, with proper spelling (forget "u", etc), and give the exact details of the technologies you are using.

Comment: working!! thanks all of u (i putted the jar where jafar ali told me)

Comment: @dennisbergkamp You are now over 15 reputation points. Now you can upvote answers, if you think they deserve it. It is a big reward to the answerer.